# Fade one side of a line in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I want to fade the line from just one side.

I tried with the Filter -> Blur -> Motion Blur.

[image]

The above screenshot shows the blur from both the sides.

But I want to do it from just one side.

Comment: You can always cut the excess off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a gradient mask to the line:

[image: gradient mask]

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with help of **Gradient**.

follow this steps :

1. first, take 1 rectangle.
2. fill it with a **gradient**.
3. make sure your angle is **zero**

[image]